# How to bind masked MudTextField to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, mudblazor

I would like to create a MudTextField and bind to a TimeSpan variable with the following mask:
hh:mm:ss

The goal if the typed input is:

- '1' the output shall be -> 00:00:01
- '12' the output shall be -> 00:00:12
- '123' the output shall be -> 00:01:23
- etc..

(output is in the same MudTextField as the input)

I have been trying to solve with the following:

```
<MudTextField Mask="@timeMask" @bind-Value="@time" Format="HH:mm:ss" Label="hh:mm:ss" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I tried on this control, but I have used the Text property to use that's displayed, not sure how typing time would work though. I suggest binding to string and then using TimeSpan.TryParse or custom code to convert it to a TimeSpan. Then the Text field could be the TimeSpan formatted.